# Filtering pandas dataframe by exact word match

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a following dataframe in pandas

```
          Date                             Title
58      March 2015        Data Visualization with JavaScript
63   December 2014          Eloquent JavaScript, 2nd Edition
90    October 2014             If Hemingway Wrote JavaScript
96   December 2014                       JavaScript for Kids
158  February 2014  Principles of Object-Oriented JavaScript
209  November 2005                          Wicked Cool Java
```

I have to filter the rows which contains word JavaScript in it. I am doing following.

```
category_javascript = np.where(Publisher['Title'].str.contains(r'(?:\s|^)JavaScript(?:\s|$)'))
```

It gives me following outupt

```
category_javascript
Out[106]: (array([ 58,  90,  96, 158], dtype=int64),)
```

It does not filter `63  December 2014   Eloquent JavaScript, 2nd Edition` I think because word JavaScript has comma after it. I want to find exact word irrespective of punctuation or combination. for e.g JavaScript-Book also would do.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you dont need regex, only string `JavaScript`:

```
category_javascript = np.where(Publisher['Title'].str.contains('JavaScript'))
```

---

```
print (Publisher['Title'].str.contains('JavaScript'))
58      True
63      True
90      True
96      True
158     True
209    False
Name: Title, dtype: bool

print (Publisher[Publisher['Title'].str.contains('JavaScript')])
              Date                                     Title
58      March 2015        Data Visualization with JavaScript
63   December 2014          Eloquent JavaScript, 2nd Edition
90    October 2014             If Hemingway Wrote JavaScript
96   December 2014                       JavaScript for Kids
158  February 2014  Principles of Object-Oriented JavaScript
```

---

You can add diacritics to regex like `[,;]`:

```
print (Publisher['Title'].str.contains('(?:\s|^|[,;])JavaScript(?:\s|$|[,;])'))
58      True
63      True
90      True
96      True
158     True
209    False
Name: Title, dtype: bool

print (Publisher['Title'].str.contains('(?:\s|^|[,;])Java(?:\s|$|[,;])'))
58     False
63     False
90     False
96     False
158    False
209     True
Name: Title, dtype: bool
```

Comment: I got your point. what if I want to extract word Java ? Then above code will return all the rows including JavaScript

Comment: Did you get what I am saying ?

Comment: Yes, give me a sec

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks a lot :)